# Unable to read lines from standard input

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin

I am trying to read lines from standard input

I want to square the positive integer from the new line, and from each line of input, I want to print the output.

Below is my code :

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var stdin = '';
var chunk = '5\n25';
process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
    stdin += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
    var lines = stdin.split('\n');
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        process.stdout.write(lines[i]*lines[i]);
    }
});
```

This is returning an error :

```
    throw new TypeError(
    ^

TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not number
```

I really dont understand where I wrote the code wrong!! Help is appreciated.

**Edit 1**
When I try to print output by appending '\n' at the end like below example : `process.stdout.write(lines[i]*lines[i] + "\n");` It is printing the output and 0 in the next line, for example if i send 5 as input it is printing : 
`25  0`
 ==> 0 gets printed on the next line! Is this an issue with utf-8 i am using?

Comment: I guess `process.stdout.write("" + lines[i]*lines[i]);`

Comment: Even it is throwing the same issue :( @JonasW.

Comment: when I try to append a new line after the output like this ==> `process.stdout.write(lines[i]*lines[i] + "\n");`
It is printing the output and 0 in the next line, for example if i send 5 as input it is printing : 
`25
0`

Answer (score 1):

```
 process.stdout.write(lines[i]*lines[i]);
```

Thats the line that causes

```
 TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not number
```

as you are trying to pass a Number to a Stream. A solution would be to convert the number to a string:

```
 process.stdout.write("" + lines[i] ** 2);
```

---

Now when you apply this it works however it always outputs a 0 after the result. Thats because every input is sent by pressing Enter, which adds `\n` to the input, e.g:

```
 1 \n 2 \n
```

Now you do this

```
 var lines = stdin.split('\n');
```

so lines will be

```
 ["1", "2", ""]
```

the squares of that will be

```
 1, 4, 0 // as "" => 0
```

so the 0 is caused by an empty line at the end of the input. So you may check for that:

```
  for(const line of stdin.split('\n')){
    if(!line) continue;
    console.log(line ** 2);
  }
```

Comment: I am able to print in the next line, Thank you very much. 
It seems `line ** 2` doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inBuilt `readline` package to accomplish your task.
The following snippet will read your input from the line and on "Enter" will shoot the response too.

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function(line){
    console.log('Square of '+line+ ' : ' + line * line );
})
```

Output:

```
ValerianP-Macbook:src valerianpereira$ node app.js
25
Square of 25 : 625
66
Square of 66 : 4356
2
Square of 2 : 4
3
Square of 3 : 9
7
Square of 7 : 49
```

Code for Manual method

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
    chunk = chunk.toString().trim();
    process.stdout.write('Square of ' + chunk + ' : ' + chunk * chunk + '\n');
});
```

Output :

```
ValerianP-Macbook:src valerianpereira$ node app.js
4
Square of 4 : 16
6
Square of 6 : 36
78
Square of 78 : 6084
22
Square of 22 : 484
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks :) ! But i want to do this manually as shown in my qsn :|

Answer (score -1):

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var stdin = '';

process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {

    stdin += chunk;

}).on('end', function() {
    var lines = stdin.split('\n');

    lines = lines.filter(Boolean);

    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {

        process.stdout.write(lines[i]*lines[i]+"\n");

    }
});
```